# How to fetch data from server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I am making an login application in which user can log in.

If the user has already register, then he should be able to log in with the same data saved on server and should be able to get alert view as success and if not the error alert.

Unfortunately, I am not able to do that.

Please help me out.

This is my code:

```
-(IBAction)btn_login: (id) sender
{

NSString *firstname = Firstname.text;

NSString *lastname = Lastname.text;

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fname=%@&lname=%@",firstname,lastname];

NSString *hostStr =@"http://www.yoursite.com/iphone.php";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];

NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

if ([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Congrats" message:@"You are authorised" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Invalid Username and password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

Firstname.text=nil;
Lastname.text=nil;

}
```

thanks

Comment: try to put breakpoint & check what's content of serverOutput...

Comment: k i will chk.....thank's

Comment: Are you getting any output from your server side or not?

Comment: nothing is found in serverOutput

Comment: if i enter correct or wrong value i get an same alert for both (i.e. Error msg)

Comment: if you are getting nothing in serverOutput...there should be problem with service

Answer (score 3):

You need to supply a "?" after the address when appending parameters.

Change

```
NSString *hostStr=@"http://www.yoursite.com/iphone.php";
```

to

```
NSString *hostStr=@"http://www.yoursite.com/iphone.php?";
```

PS: NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl is a horrible way to do this. Use NSURLConnection and use authentication challenge for Basic Authentication. Read [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).